# hibernate support for deferred constraints?

Tags: sql, hibernate, constraints

In Hibernate 3.6, what is the support for deferred constraints?

As I get it, in 3.2, "Hibernate does not have support for deferred constraints."
(from http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2248)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you linked was originally filed against Hibernate 3.2. It does not yet have a fix version and the status is open, which implies that the issue still exists and deferred constraints is not yet supported in any version of Hibernate.